# How do I find a running container by name?

Tags: docker

the `docker ps` command supports a `--filter name=X` that unfortunately matches any part of the name.  so the above will return *both* containers: `X` and `XY`.  I tried a regex `name='^X$'` but it didn't work

how can I determine whether a container is running by name?

Comment: An alternative approach is to just use grep: `docker ps | grep " some_name "`.  Notice the spaces before and after `some_name`

Comment: I've ended up doing: `docker ps --format="{{.Names}}" |grep '^X$'` but it just seems to me like a poor choice to assume partial matches are the best choice

Comment: If you know the exact container name, you can skip the `docker ps` and go straight to the `docker container inspect` with a format for whatever values you need.

Comment: and just let the inspect break if the container doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but JFTR:
There's a helpful post at [docker.com Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-filter-docker-ps-by-exact-name/2880) that propagates the "grep"-approach but even shows the following "docker only" way:

> For a container named foo:
>
> `docker ps -a --no-trunc --filter name=^/foo$`

what makes another answer to your question as:

```
docker ps --filter name=^/X$
```

Comment: interesting.  I had tried it with quotes (as you can see from the OP), which failed

Comment: I didn't get the syntax at this point myself to the full extend as it looks like some regex, but doesn't work in any other aspect as a regex - at least what I tried until now.
But for the exact name case it works well.

Comment: so you're saying your solution doesn't actually work? (I didn't try it)

Comment: No, this solution above **does work** for the exact name case!

But if these pattern should be regex - there would be more possibilities for filtering. There my extended tests didn't work as I tried

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `docker container inspect`. To see if the container exists, check the error status of the command with an `if` in `/bin/sh` or `bash`:

```bash
if [ "$(docker container inspect --format '{{.State.Status}}' $container_name 2>&1)" == "running" ]; then
  echo "running"
else
  echo "not_running"
fi
```

Comment: Not sure if this counts as "running", as this would evaluate to true, even if the container status is exited. The container might still exist and be inspect-able. Though, you could do this, in combination with `| jq .[].State.Status` and check if it is running. Something like `[ $(docker container inspect <NAME>  | jq .[].State.Status -r) == "running" ]`, followed by `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ...`

Comment: To avoid outputting errors: `[ "$(docker container inspect <NAME>  2>/dev/null | jq .[].State.Status -r)" == "running" ]`